# Because 'flutter App' depends on snippetcoder_utils any which doesn't exist, version solving failed

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, flutter-dependencies

I'm trying to use the snippetcoder utils dependency but after I run pub get, I get this error "Because qr_scanner depends on snippetcoder_utils any which doesn't exist (could not find package snippetcoder_utils at [here](https://pub.dartlang.org)), version solving failed."

dependencies:
flutter:
sdk: flutter
qr_code_scanner: ^0.4.0
url_launcher: ^6.0.3
mysql1: ^0.19.2
http: ^0.13.4
snippetcoder_utils: ^1.0.12

Answer (score 0):

Stop the app from running then do `flutter clean` then do this in your terminal `flutter pub add snippet_coder_utils` this worked for me as I initially got the same error as yours.

Comment: Did all as instructed and run but still getting the same error

Comment: Check my updated code.

Comment: Mark as right/upvote if it did help  you

Comment: THIS IS WHAT I GOT



Deleting build...                                                    6ms

C:\Users\BAIDEN\StudioProjects\e_humanis_flutter>flutter pub add snippet_coder_utils
Because qr_scanner depends on snippetcoder_utils any which doesn't exist (could not find package snippetcoder_utils at https://pub.dartlang.org), version solving failed.
pub finished with exit code 65

Comment: Please remove both `qr_code_scanner:` and `snippetcoder_utils:` from your pubspec.yaml file and clean from your terminal `flutter clean` then do `flutter pub add snippet_coder_utils` then add the rest of the dependencies in the .yaml

Comment: Make sure you do not have those dependencies in your .yaml file

Comment: Mark as right/upvote